# Topological vector space question

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

$C[0,1]=$ space of all continuous complex valued function over $[0,1]$.

Define metric,

$d(f,g)={\int_{0}^{1} \frac {|f(x)-g(x)|}{1+|f(x)-g(x)|}}$, for all $f,g\in C[0,1] .$

Let $(C[0,1],\sigma)$ be the topology induced by $d$.

How to prove this topology has only convex open sets $\emptyset$ and $C[0,1]$.

Comment: Maybe useful: http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/fun/ell_p_not_convex.pdf. I think that the essential idea that can be applied here is "Local convexity would require that the convex hull of the $\delta$-ball at 0 be contained in some $r$-ball."

Comment: Consider a (finite) partition of unity $\{\varphi_k : 1 \leqslant k \leqslant 2n\}$ such that the support of each $\varphi_k$ has diameter $\leqslant \frac{1}{n}$. Write $$f = \sum_{k=1}^{2n} \frac{1}{2n}(2n\varphi_k\cdot f).$$